# Countdown js clock not working when run locally but working on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

*Note the following code is completed copy and pasted, I do not know js but want to add this one feature of a countdown clock to my site (original code found at https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq)

here is the code (jsfiddle included at bottom)

```
<head>
<script>
  function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
      var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      var clock = document.getElementById(id);
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

      function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
      }

      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
    <div id="clockdiv">
      <div> 
        <span class="days"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="hours"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="minutes"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="seconds"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mktc6q4n/

Does anyone know why this is not working locally in my browser?

Comment: do you have any error like cross-origin in the console ?

Comment: I see `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'clock.querySelector')`

Comment: because the DOM hasn't been parsed by the time you look up the element. If you pay attention to the JS options on JSFiddle you'll see it wraps the code you write in an onload. Move your JS to the end of the body or wait for the onload event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your javascript is being executed before the HTML is rendered. You have 2 options to fix this

Load the script tag at the end of the `<body>` tag, so you can copy this snippet

```
<body>
  <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
  </script>
</body>
```

Wait till the DOM is completely loaded with

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // do stuff
  }, false);

</script>
```

So, copying this will make it work as well

```
<head>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
          'total': t,
          'days': days,
          'hours': hours,
          'minutes': minutes,
          'seconds': seconds
        };
      }

      function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
          var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

          daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
          hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
          minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
          secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

          if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
          }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
      }

      var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
    }, false);

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span class="days"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="hours"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="minutes"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="seconds"></span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here you have a small tutorial on how to get started with HTML, CSS and Javascript. I hope it helps

[How TO - Build a Website](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_website.asp)

Comment: this may be the answer. its all working on my local chrome and safari browsers

Comment: sorry, I did not see your code properly. The first snippet I posted works, but the explanation was not ok. I updated my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the function initializeClock when the elements haven't been loaded yet. Meaning that the div (id clockdiv) does not exist yet, so the query selector can't find it and returns null.

Moving the script to the end of the body should solve it (lazy fix).

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            text-align: center;
            background: #00ECB9;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #396;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-size: 40px;
            margin: 40px 0px 20px;
        }

        #clockdiv {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: #fff;
            display: inline-block;
            font-weight: 100;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        #clockdiv > div {
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background: #00BF96;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #clockdiv div > span {
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background: #00816A;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .smalltext {
            padding-top: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
                var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
                var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
                var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
                var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                return {
                    'total': t,
                    'days': days,
                    'hours': hours,
                    'minutes': minutes,
                    'seconds': seconds
                };
            }

            function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
                var clock = document.getElementById(id);
                var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
                var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
                var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
                var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

                function updateClock() {
                    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

                    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
                    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
                    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
                    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

                    if (t.total <= 0) {
                        clearInterval(timeinterval);
                    }
                }

                updateClock();
                var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
            }

            var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
        <span class="days"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="hours"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="minutes"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="seconds"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript in the `head` is not being executing because it is not inside the `body` or attached to any event. You run it when the page loads with `window.onload = function(){}` or you can place at the end of the `body`.

You can copy any of the following snippets.

Function run when the window loads:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
}
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

</script>
<style>
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div> 
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script at end of `body`:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div> 
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```